# Multiple CSS background-image's on Mobile

Tags: ios, css, background-image

I've created a grid pattern using css background-images as follows:

```
.grid {
    width:720px;
    height:720px;

    background-color: #333333;

    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,0.1), 1px, transparent 1px),
                      linear-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,0.5), 1px, transparent 1px),
                      linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(255,255,255,0.1), 1px, transparent 1px),
                      linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(255,255,255,0.5), 1px, transparent 1px);

    background-size: 40px 40px,
                     240px 240px,
                     40px 40px,
                     240px 240px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nicholasstephan/47zyx3pq/1/

but while this works on just about all desktop browsers, it isn't showing in either Safari or Chrome on iOS. What gives?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you have a slight syntax error, instead of

```
linear-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,0.1), 1px, transparent 1px)
```

it should be

```
linear-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,0.1) 1px, transparent 1px)
```

And second, setting the visible part of the gradient to 1px on a retina display can give you problems if you are not setting ok the viewport to avoid zooming /rescaling . Have you tried setting it to 2px, or even larger ?

Comment: It was that extra comma. Typo on my part that I didn't see. Thanks!